# Проблема в цикле

Tags: java, циклы, while

Есть код для игры в крестики нолики.
Проблема в том что цикл проходит только один раз, а потом всегда останавливается.

```
while (!gameOver) {

        x1 = scan.nextInt();
        y1 = scan.nextInt();

        table[x1][y1] = 'X';

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        x2 = scan.nextInt();
        y2 = scan.nextInt();

        table[x2][y2] = 'O';

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (    ( (table[0][0] == table[0][1]) && (table[0][0] == table[0][2]) && (table[0][0] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[0][0] == table[1][0]) && (table[0][0] == table[2][0]) && (table[0][0] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[0][1] == table[1][1]) && (table[0][1] == table[2][1]) && (table[0][1] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[0][2] == table[1][2]) && (table[0][2] == table[2][2]) && (table[0][2] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[1][0] == table[1][1]) && (table[1][0] == table[1][2]) && (table[1][0] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[2][0] == table[2][1]) && (table[2][0] == table[2][2]) && (table[2][0] != ' ') ) ||
                ( (table[2][0] == table[1][1]) && (table[2][0] == table[0][2]) && (table[2][0] != ' ') )
        ) {
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }
```

не бомбите на условие пожалуйста, только начинаю кодить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка скорее всего из-за того, что ваш двумерный массив изначально не проинициалицирован пробелами, так как по логике цикл рабочий.

А по логике самой игры, проверку лучше делать после каждого хода.

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что массив был не заполнен, спасибо.